# Button disabled until drop down list is selected - Material Design

Tags: jquery, html, css, material-design

I am using Material Design css and I want to disable next button until the drop down list value is selected using jquery.

```
 <div class="mdl-selectfield mdl-js-selectfield">
    <select class="mdl-selectfield__select" id="ad_duration">
      <option value=""></option>
      <option value="option1">option 1</option>
      <option value="option2">option 2</option>
      <option value="option3">option 3</option>
      <option value="option4">option 4</option>
      <option value="option5">option 5</option>
    </select>
  </div>

<br><br><br>
<button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-js-ripple-effect"  id="submitorder">
  Next
</button>


$('#submitorder').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
$('#ad_duration').change(updateFormEnabled);

function updateFormEnabled() {
    if (verifyAdSettings()) {
        $('#submitorder').attr('disabled', '');
    } else {
        $('#submitorder').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
}

function verifyAdSettings() {
    if ($('#ad_duration').val() != '') {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false
    }
}
```

It worked just fine without mdl-selectfield.
https://codepen.io/inouekun/pen/XeLyaY

Answer (score 0):

Instead of "attr" use "prop" instead. Because -- (Copied from other answer) -- Why use prop() when you could use attr()/removeAttr() to do this? Basically, prop() should be used when getting or setting properties (such as autoplay, checked, disabled and required amongst others).

By using removeAttr(), you are completely removing the disabled attribute itself - while prop() is merely setting the property's underlying boolean value to false.

```
    $('#submitorder').prop('disabled', true);
    $('#ad_duration').change(updateFormEnabled);

    function updateFormEnabled() {
        console.log("update");
        if (verifyAdSettings()) {
            console.log("ok");
            $('#submitorder').prop('disabled', false);
        } else {
            console.log("not ok");
            $('#submitorder').prop('disabled', true);
        }
    }

    function verifyAdSettings() {
        console.log("verify");
        if ($('#ad_duration').val() != '') {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: It worked just fine with attr, so there's no reason to change to prop. The problem is it didn't work when I use with <div class="mdl-selectfield mdl-js-selectfield">. I tried changing to prop and it became haywire.

Here's the working code when I commented out the mdl-selectfield: https://codepen.io/inouekun/pen/VMoEvW

Comment: People uses prop instead of attr is because they're using jquery v3.2.1 instead of older version. Basically both function are the same. Correct me if I'm wrong.